# Connecting postgres docker instance to dotnet core 3.1 gives "nodename nor servname provided, or not known error"

Tags: postgresql, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a postgres sql spun up using docker with the following `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3.8'
  services:
    db:
      image: postgres:latest
      container_name: quoters
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}
        POSTGRES_DB: quoters
      networks:
        - quoters
      volumes:
        - quoters:/data/db/quoters
        - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      restart: always
  networks:
    quoters:
      driver: bridge

  volumes:
    quoters:
```

I am trying to connect to this postgres sql instance locally from my `dotnet` core `webapi` application. Below is my `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": 
     "host=db;port=5432;database=quoters;username=postgres;password=password"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I get the connectionString and use it in the `Startup.cs` file with the following line

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddRepository(connectionString);
```

The `services.AddRepository(string)` is an extension method I created. I then use this connectionString in an `ISqlConnectionFactory` implementation.

When I try to test the `API` on `Swagger`, I get the following error

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): nodename nor servname provided, or not known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
```

I can't seem to place a finger on what is wrong. (I have a feeling something is off with my connectionString).
Please any help on resolving this issue will be appreciated

#### Additional information

- I am using `macOS Catalina` version `10.15.7`

Answer (score 3):

Change your connection string to

```
"User ID=postgres;Password=changeme;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database= quoters;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
```